# How to read the input json using a schema file and populate default value if column not being found in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**Input Dataframe**

```
val input_json="""[{"orderid":"111","customers":{"customerId":"123"},"Offers":[{"Offerid":"1"},{"Offerid":"2"}]}]""";
val inputdataRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(input_json :: Nil);
val inputdataRdddf = spark.read.json(inputdataRdd);
inputdataRdddf.show();
```

**schema df**

```
 val schema_json="""[{"orders":{"order_id":{"path":"orderid","type":"string","nullable":false},"customer_id":{"path":"customers.customerId","type":"int","nullable":false,"default_value":"null"},"offer_id":{"path":"Offers.Offerid","type":"string","nullable":false},"eligible":{"path":"eligible.eligiblestatus","type":"string","nullable":true,"default_value":"not eligible"}},"products":{"product_id":{"path":"product_id","type":"string","nullable":false},"product_name":{"path":"products.productname","type":"string","nullable":false}}}]""";
val schemaRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(schema_json :: Nil);
val schemaRdddf = spark.read.json(schemaRdd);
schemaRdddf.show();
```

[image]

using the schema df , i want to read all the columns from the input dataframe.

1. if the nullable key is true then i want to populate the column with default value (if the column is not present or not having any data).
   In the above example, eligible.eligiblestatus is not present hence i want to populate with some default value
2. Also i want to change the data type of the columns based in type key defined in the schema json. . e.g customer id is of type INT in schema json but in input dataframe it is coming as string, hence i want to cast it to integer.
3. the final column name should be taken from the key from schema json. e.g order_id is the key for orderid attribute

Final DF should have columns like:

```
order_id:String,customer_id:int, offer_id: string(array type cast to string),eligiblestatus:string
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the code below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, StructType}
```

```
val input =
  """[{"orderid":"111","customers":{"customerId":"123"},"Offers":[{"Offerid":"1"},{"Offerid":"2"}]}]"""
val schema =
  """[{"orders":{"order_id":{"path":"orderid","type":"string","nullable":false},"customer_id":{"path":"customers.customerId","type":"int","nullable":false,"default_value":"null"},"offer_id":{"path":"Offers.Offerid","type":"string","nullable":false},"eligible":{"path":"eligible.eligiblestatus","type":"string","nullable":true,"default_value":"not eligible"}},"products":{"product_id":{"path":"product_id","type":"string","nullable":false},"product_name":{"path":"products.productname","type":"string","nullable":false}}}]"""
```

```
val jsonSchema = """
      map<
        string, 
        struct<
            path:string,
            type:string,
            nullable:string,
            default_value:string  
        >
      >
    """
```

```
val inputDF = spark.read.json(Seq(input).toDS)
val inputFieldMap = typedLit(inputDF.fields.map(f => f -> f).toMap)
val schemaColumns = Seq("orders") // You can get this from variable.
val schemaDF = spark.read.json(Seq(schema).toDS).selectExpr(schemaColumns:_*)
```

Helper class to get nested columns from dataframe.

```
implicit class DFHelpers(df: DataFrame) {
  def fields: Seq[String] =
    this.fields(df.schema)
  def fields(
      schema: StructType = df.schema,
      root: String = "",
      sep: String = "."
  ): Seq[String] = {
    schema.fields.flatMap { column =>
      column match {
        case _ if column.dataType.isInstanceOf[StructType] =>
          fields(
            column.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType],
            s"${root}${sep}${column.name}".stripPrefix(sep)
          )
        case _ if column.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType] =>
          column.dataType
            .asInstanceOf[ArrayType]
            .productIterator
            .filter(_.isInstanceOf[StructType])
            .map(_.asInstanceOf[StructType])
            .flatMap(f => fields(f, s"${root}${sep}${column.name}".stripPrefix(sep)))
        case _ => Seq(s"${root}${sep}${column.name}".stripPrefix(sep))
      }
    }.toList
  }
}
```

```
val schemaExprs = schemaDF.columns.map { columnName =>
  s"""
    filter(
       transform(
          map_entries(
             ${columnName}),
             e ->
                CASE WHEN fields[e.value.path] IS NOT NULL THEN
                     IF(
                        e.value.nullable == 'true', 
                        CONCAT("CAST( NVL(",e.value.path,",'",e.value.default_value,"') AS ",e.value.type," )"," AS ",e.key), 
                        CONCAT("CAST( ",e.value.path, " AS ",e.value.type," )"," AS ",e.key)
                     )
                 END
          ),
       f -> f IS NOT NULL
    ) AS ${columnName}
  """
}
```

```
val columns = schemaDF
  .selectExpr(
    schemaDF.columns.map(c =>
      s"from_json(to_json(${c}), '${jsonSchema}') AS ${c}"
    ): _*
  )
  .withColumn("fields", inputFieldMap)// Checking if inputDF fields exist in the schemaDF, if not, default values will be used; if default values are not available, the column will be removed.
  .selectExpr(schemaExprs: _*)
  .select(schemaDF.columns.map(col(_)).reduce(array_union).as("columns"))
  .as[Seq[String]]
  .collect()
  .flatten
```

```
inputDF.selectExpr(columns: _*).show(false)
```

```
+-----------+------------+--------+--------+
|customer_id|eligible    |offer_id|order_id|
+-----------+------------+--------+--------+
|123        |not eligible|[1, 2]  |111     |
+-----------+------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: since i am only trying to get the fields as mentioned under orders key. how do i pass that as variable to this code

Comment: input json will be diffrent for product and orders. hence the job i am writing it will be specific to orders. Hence want to send Orders as variable to get that part from the schema json

Comment: Can you check this use case. If eligible key is present for one record and not for other. For the other eligible status should  be default value. I mean wherever nullable is true, if the attribute is null/not exist it should populate default value: [{
    "orderid": "111",
    "customers": {
        "customerId": "123"
    },
    "Offers": [{
        "Offerid": "1"
    }, {
        "Offerid": "2"
    }]
}, {
    "orderid": "123",
    "Offers": [{
        "Offerid": "1"
    }, {
        "Offerid": "2"
    }],
    "eligible": {
        "eligiblestatus": "active"
    }
}]

Comment: basically in second when condition(ref schemaExprs) , i need to put nvl

Comment: tried to do, but parsing error is coming. possible for you to update the schemaExprs

Comment: sure, give me some time will update.

Comment: let me know if were able to put that nvl statement

Comment: done, made changes in `schemaExprs`